# How to throw an exception if parsing with Long.parseLong() fails?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to write some kind of a stack calculator.

Here is a part of my code where I am handling a `push` command. I want to push integers only, so I have to get rid of any invalid strings like `foobar` (which cannot be parsed into integer) or `999999999999` (which exceeds the integer range).

`strings` in my code is a table of strings containing commands like `POP` or `PUSH`, numbers, and random clutter already split by white characters.

### Main problem:

I've got difficulties with throwing an exception for `long parseNumber = Long.parseLong(strings[i]);` - I don't know how to handle the case, when `strings[i]` cannot be parsed into a `long` and subsequently into an `integer`.

```
while (i < strings.length) {
  try {
    if (strings[i].equals("PUSH")) {
      // PUSH 
      i++;
      if (strings[i].length() > 10)
        throw new OverflowException(strings[i]);
      // How to throw an exception when it is not possible to parse 
      // the string?
      long parseNumber = Long.parseLong(strings[i]); 
      
      if (parseNumber > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        throw new OverflowException(strings[i]);
      
      if (parseNumber < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        throw new UnderflowException(strings[i]);
      number = (int)parseNumber;
      stack.push(number);      
    }
    // Some options like POP, ADD, etc. are omitted here
    // because they are of little importance.
  }
  catch (InvalidInputException e)
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  catch (OverflowException e)
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  catch (UnderflowException e)
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  finally {
    i++;
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Long.parseLong throws a NumberFormatException if the string cannot be parsed. You can wrap that in a try-catch to catch cases where the string is not a long.

Comment: @nullPointer, ok so the idea is that I can make another try-catch just for the `long parseNumber = Long.parseLong(strings[i]);` if I want to add my own exception for the sake of the exercise, right?

Comment: @Mateusz that is correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Long.parseLong(String str)` throws a `NumberFormatException` if the string cannot be parsed by any reason. You can catch the same by adding a catch block for your try, as below:

```
catch ( NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to worry. `Long.parseLong()` throws a `NumberFormatException` if it got other than a `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments and answers I was able to come up with such a solution (this code is embedded inside the outside `try-catch`.)

```
if (strings[i].equals("PUSH")) {
  // PUSH 
  i++;
  if (strings[i].length() > 10) {
    throw new OverflowException(strings[i]);
  }

  try{
    parseNumber = Long.parseLong(strings[i]);

    if (parseNumber > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
      throw new OverflowException(strings[i]);
    }

    if (parseNumber < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
      throw new UnderflowException(strings[i]);
    }

    number = (int)parseNumber;
    stack.push(number);

  }
  catch (NumberFormatException n){
    throw new InvalidInputException(strings[i]);
  }                 
}
```